# Embedded model does not display from cache

Tags: ember.js

When trying to load embedded data, I have a problem in that when the model is already cached on my page, this embedded data will not load in the view. If, however, it it is reloaded from scratch and therefore read from the API, it does load. I can see that the data is being loaded into the model from the Ember inspector plugin, however. 
If you could tell me the issue here so that the data will load every time, this would be appreciated. 
Many thanks.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import WebApiSerializer from 'ember-web-api/serializers/web-api';

export default WebApiSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
    attrs: {
        subjects: { embedded: 'always' }
    }
});
```

Models

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    graduationDate: DS.attr('string'),
    institutionLevel : DS.attr('string'),
    subjects: DS.hasMany('subject'),
    cv: DS.belongsTo('cv')
});

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'), 
    grade: DS.attr('string'), 
    education: DS.belongsTo('education')
});
```

Comment: Can you specify which versions you are using? In Ember Data 2.x all relationships are async, which you don't want.

Comment: Ember 2.2, It is async but handlebars should display the data once the promise is resolved?

Comment: an embedded relationship can't be async, because it's embedded in the resource. If that's not the problem you'll need to provide more context to help figure out the problem.